# Sketching $y=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$

Tags: calculus

I am on a curve sketching unit, and im trying to graph the function:

$y=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$

I have tried using the first derivative test to find local max or min, and increasing decreasing intervals but when i take the derivative and set it to zero, i find that the test fails. I can find the x, and y intercepts by setting y=0 and x=0 respectively.

Any tips on how to sketch this function. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to observe is that, for large $x$, the first term is roughly the same as $x$ (albeit always a bit bigger). What does this tell you about the behavior on the positive $x$ axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the limits as $x \to -\infty$ and $x \to +\infty $ in order to identify the asymptotes.

Notice that 
$$lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+1} - x  = 0$$

And it has an oblique asymptote when $x \to -\infty$. In fact, if we write $y = ax + b$, then

$$a = \text{lim}_{x\to+\infty}\  \frac{f(x)}{x}\ \   and\ \   b = \text{lim}_{x\to-\infty}\  f(x) - ax$$

Thus $$a = \text{lim}_{x\to-\infty}\  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} - x}{x} = -2 \\\ \ \text{and}\ \ \\\ b = \text{lim}_{x\to-\infty}\ \sqrt{x^2+1} - x  + 2x = \text{lim}_{x\to-\infty}\ \sqrt{x^2+1} + x = 0 $$

Then $y = -2x$ is an oblique asymptote.

It will look like this

$\hskip1.5in$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will give you some intuition:
$$\sqrt{x^2+1} - x = x\sqrt{1 + 1/x^2} - x = x\Big(\sqrt{1+1/x^2}-1\Big)$$
and the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+1/x^2}$ is $1+1/(2x^2) + O(x^{-4})$ so
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1} = x\Big(\sqrt{1+1/x^2}-1\Big) \approx x\big(1+1/(2x^2) + O(x^{-4}) - 1\big) =  1/(2x)+O(x^{-3}).
$$